# how to solve fopen64, freopen64, tmpfile64 not declared errors?

Tags: android, qt, dcmtk

I have compiled DCMTK source code to generate libs(for android platform) and adding these libs in my QT project. While building my qt project I am getting these errors:

```
C:\Ashish\QTPROJECT\test\include\dcmtk\ofstd\offile.h:310: error: '::fopen64' has not been declared
file_ = :: fopen64(filename, modes);
^
C:\Ashish\QTPROJECT\test\include\dcmtk\ofstd\offile.h:425: error: '::freopen64' has not been declared
file_ = :: freopen64(filename, modes, file_);
^
C:\Ashish\QTPROJECT\test\include\dcmtk\ofstd\offile.h:444: error: '::tmpfile64' has not been declared
file_ = :: tmpfile64();
^
C:\Ashish\QTPROJECT\test\include\dcmtk\ofstd\offile.h:790: error: '::fseeko64' has not been declared
result = :: fseeko64(file_, off, whence);
^
C:\Ashish\QTPROJECT\test\include\dcmtk\ofstd\offile.h:823: error: '::ftello64' has not been declared
result = :: ftello64(file_);
^
C:\Ashish\QTPROJECT\test\include\dcmtk\ofstd\offile.h:847: error: '::fgetpos64' has not been declared
result = :: fgetpos64(file_, pos);
^
C:\Ashish\QTPROJECT\test\include\dcmtk\ofstd\offile.h:867: error: '::fsetpos64' has not been declared
result = :: fsetpos64(file_, pos);
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue.
problem was that Libs I was using were compiled in debug so the solution is while creating libs I should use release instead of debug and then add those libs in the project and then such errors will not occur.